# When is it correct to use a comma between two consecutive adjectives qualifying the same noun?

Tags: commas

It is a subtle, complicated idea.

We went to an expensive summer resort.

Why is there a comma between the adjectives in the first sentence but not in the second one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Subtle' and 'complicated' *both* describe 'idea', and so are *coordinate adjectives*. These can be separated by commas. It may be helpful to replace the commas with 'and'. If the sentence still makes sense, the adjectives are coordinate, and commas may separate the adjectives. 'A subtle and complicated idea' makes sense.

'Expensive' describes 'summer resort'. 'An expensive and summer resort' makes no sense; the adjectives are not coordinate.

[When to Omit Commas between Multiple Adjectives Preceding a Noun](https://style.mla.org/coordinate-adjectives-commas/)

Comment: Umm, I think I made a little mistake while writing the example.  It is subtle not simple. This is a subtle,complicated idea.

Comment: @Rayhan - they are still coordinate adjectives.